# "No windows have a root view controller, cannot save application state" when trying to persist iOS app state

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, state-restoration

I want to adopt the state restoration in my app. I've opted out of using SceneDelegate because my app is not supposed to be running in multiple windows.

So I've implemented the necessary methods in my AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

But every time I quit the app I get this message in the debugger

```
No windows have a root view controller, cannot save application state
```

I setup my window programmatically at the launch of app like this

```
func configureWindow() {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        let launchViewController = Storyboard.launch.instantiate() as LaunchViewController
        launchViewController.viewModel = LaunchViewModel(context: context)
        window.rootViewController = RootNavigationController(rootViewController: launchViewController)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        self.window = window
    }
```

So I don't see how is it possible that at the time the app gets killed it has no `rootViewController`.

This definitely seems like a bug to me, but has anyone encountered such issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I've opted out of using SceneDelegate because my app is not supposed to be running in multiple windows.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66313971/19039804) answer, it links to the article, that says

> The best way to implement UI state restoration is to make your app scene-based

Comment: Funny thing is, when I leave my SceneDelegate as it is and implement the old-fashioned state restoration the issue is gone. I’ll probably go with the Scene approach but I’m pretty sure it’s a bug, the message from debugger just doesn’t make sense